# Do I need to install SQLite so that SQLiteJDBC works?

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

I guess I'm just not "getting it". If I don't have SQLite already installed on my computer, and I want to write a Java app that uses an embedded database, and I download/import the SQLiteJDBC JAR into my project, is that all I need? Or, do I need to first install SQLite before and create a database file for my SQLiteJDBC code to connect to and run queries from?

If that's the case, and its not sufficient to just download/import SQLiteJDBC, then doesn't that mean that I'll have to make sure SQLite is installed on every system that I want to run my Java app on? And doesn't *that* defeat the purpose of a portable/embedded database?

Basically, I'm getting hung up on the SQLiteJDBC tutorials because:

1. They don't tell you how HelloWorld.sqlite gets created (does SQLiteJDBC create it for you, do you have to create it in SQLite first from the command prompt, etc.); and
2. They never clarify whether SQLiteJDBC is dependent on SQLite for the API calls to work

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: H2 is a good pure Java alternative (single jar dependency), which can be used as in memory, file based or in server mode.

Comment: Hello Massie, welcome to Stack Overflow! – Please try to find a bit more descriptive titles (like the one I just edited) in future – this way your questions will be easier to answer, and also more useful for future visitors. As a side note: You can format numbered lists by simply putting the numbers (`1. `, `2. `) instead of using HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put the SQLLite JAR in the CLASSPATH of your app.  There's no "install" beyond that.

Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.javaworkspace.com/connectdatabase/connectSQLite.do) can help you.

Here's [another](http://java.dzone.com/articles/sqljet-pure-java-way-work) that shows how to create a database and tables.

Comment: I'm in NetBeans. Does that mean Project Properties >> Libraries >> {Compile, Processor or Run} (which one)? Then, once it is added to the CLASSPATH, and I want to use con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:HelloWorld.sqlite"); as my connection string, does SQLiteJDBC create the HelloWorld.sqlite database for me automatically? And thanks for the hint!

Comment: Add it to compile.  No, it doesn't create the database for you.  You have to do that and create the tables, too.