# Error while starting a runnable jar: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, jar, classpath, runnable

I have only the jar-file of an application. While starting it, i get the following message:

`No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:...path_of_the_db.`

I already checked similar questions and am confident that it is not a dublicate.

According to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051975/do-i-need-to-install-sqlite-so-that-sqlitejdbc-works) SQLLite Jar need to be put the in the CLASSPATH of the app.

Now my problem is how to put the SQLLite Jar in the Classpath of the app. Besides the solution which is sketchilly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581978/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcsqlite). Because you always need to search for the location of the SQLLite on the system and also type it in the console any time you start the app. (I don't have the source code of the program.)

Another question is if there is any possibility to include the SQLLite Jar while creating the Jar-file for the application. If it is not the case maybe there is another option which allows to create a runnable jar without setting the Classpath on foreign systems?

Thanks